# has_many relation via IDs list in parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, database-design, mongoid

I got in trouble while designing data model.

I have master object "A" with its children "B", and "B" has many "C", but some "C" can also be free (not belong to any "B").

By standard mas_many/belongs_to Mongoid relationd foreign key stores in "C". And it's not so awful, it works fine even when it orphan, but I think it's not looks good. Is there any way make Mongoid to store children IDs in parent's list field?

Comment: So you want A to know about its B Cs? You could explain a little better what your models look like and what you want to do with them, also give better names like foo, bar, and baz or something

Comment: No, I want B knows about it Cs, but C know nothing about B

Comment: so why do you think the array is necessary?

Comment: I think this is oblivious approach, and in my case I need to find C, B owns more often then finding Cc parent

Comment: if you add an index to b_id on C, the performance might be better than quering an array of ids.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe sounds like `belongs to many` and there is a way to achieve that by using [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_and_belongs_to_many) relation on B class.

But in my opinion your initial approach is semantically better, but its up to you to choose.

Answer (score 0):

For future viewers....

I ended using:

- [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](https://mongoid.github.io/old/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_and_belongs_to_many) on B
- `belongs_to` on C

And in the [`before_add`](https://mongoid.github.io/old/en/mongoid/docs/callbacks.html#relation_callbacks) callback from the has_and_belongs_to_many, I added something like `object_to_add.c_id ||= self.id`. This way you can have the IDs listed in the parent.

Example with a Playlist with multiple Categories:

```
class Playlist
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, before_add: :add_playlist_id, inverse_of: :playlist

  private

  def add_playlist_id(category)
    category.playlist_id ||= id
  end
end


class Category
  belongs_to :playlist, inverse_of: :categories
end
```